# See how Visual Studio compiles my project so I can compile it from command line

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a Visual Studio (.Net) project. When I hit the rebuild option in VS it compiles perfectly. In the Output window I only see the progress but it doesn't show how Visual Studio is compiling (compiler, arguments, etc. etc.)

How can I see the exact thing visual studio is executing in order to compile my solution?

Comment: Is there any reason you want to see it?

Comment: Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > MSBuild project build output verbosity = Detailed.  Rebuild the project and look in the Output directory.  Probably best to copy/paste it.  You are expected to be discouraged, using MSBuild from the command line is really rather best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Visual Studio and in the Quick Launch (Ctrl+Q) window type "MSBuild".

[image]

Then in the window that pops up, change the msbuild project output verbosity to Detailed.  Or, play around with the settings to get the amount of output that you like.

[image]

Comment: Let me know if this has helped or not.